# New to SQL - speed up using indexing

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL databases and have created a mySQL table with the following columns:

```
MJD (FLOAT) - may be duplicate 
WAVELNTH (LONG) - one of ~10 values
EXPTIME (FLOAT)
DATAMEAN (FLOAT)
FLUX (FLOAT)
```

A typical entry is something like:

A typical entry in the database looks like this:

```
MJD 55329.017334, 
WAVELNTH 131
EXPTIME 2.9
DATAMEAN 8.06
FLUX 2.78
```

In total the database has 157,502,333 entries.

My queries are almost excusively

```
SELECT (MJD, FLUX) FROM t 
WHERE (MJD > value1 and MJD < value2 and WAVELNTH=value3)
```

Right now it takes about a minute to execute a single query. I'm very new to indexing so was hoping for some help in a) how best to add an index and b) how to then use that index in my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (WAVELNTH, MJD, FLUX);
```

The first two columns `WAVELNTH` and `MJD`, appear in the `WHERE` clause, and be used to potentially restrict the number of records which need to be considered in the query.  It is not clear without more information what the order should be.  Hence, the following index might be better:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (MJD, WAVELNTH, FLUX);
```

The reason why we include `FLUX` at the end of the index is to *cover* the values in that column.  Since your select requests `MJD` and `FLUX` most likely any index would need to have both of these columns in order for MySQL to use the index.

Comment: It would be good to explain the reasoning behind using this index which has a different order of columns and why its better than the one posted

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph On a cell phone, with a particularly bad keyboard.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, thanks for your suggestion! I've edited the original post to show a typical entry. I'm also not sure why the ordering matters, and therefore how best to determine the ordering. Thanks again!

Comment: Please don't put my answer in your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I had already tried the indexing you suggested and included it in the section on what I had already tried, I certainly wasn't claiming your answer as my own. As I say, I'm very new to indexing so I appreciate your answer (which confirmed what I had tried) and I would certainly value your input on the ordering of the elements in the index creation.

Comment: `FLUX` goes last, not sure about the order of the first two.  Try both and see what works best.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help, I really appreciate it!